Weird single point anomalies in TLE data eccentricity parameter
When looking at the TLE data, I noticed weird anomalies in eccentricity for some satellites. These anomalies consist only of single data point, and data before and after them do not change trend. When compared to known dataset of manoeuvres, nothing interesting is happening at the times of those anomalies. My guess is that it is either a measurement problem, or glitch in TLE data calculation algorithm. However, since TLE data are averaged over several measurements, I still find those single point anomalies baffling, since I would expect a measurement error to also influence neighbouring datapoints.
Does anyone know what is going on?
Attached is plot a of eccentricity for Jason-1 satellite, Norad 26997. Data are obtained from space-track.org

edit: Added graph depicting other orbital elements for Jason-1 satellite, since it seems that glitches in data are accompanied by corresponding glitches in other parameters.


ehm, that domain does not exist. You might want to include a link to the actual data or at least include some excerpt of your data here. Also did you look at the data themselves for any oddities, like zeros, NAN or whatever?

Perhaps this is the intended link? https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/graph-orbit-data.php?CATNR=26997

The information needed to answer this question is not public.  The crucial thing is how many measurements went into each fit, and what kind of outlier detection and removal their orbit determination process was using at the time.  The orbit of the Jason satellites was painstakingly crafted to change extremely little over time, so I suspect they don't devote much of their limited observational resources to monitoring it.  My wild guess is those spikes were times when the number of measurements used in the fit was really small, and outlier editing did something weird, but I really don't know.

@planetmaker one can not directly link to data inside space-track.org, and this eccentricity IS the data itself.

There is a marked change in behavior between before March 2012 versus after March 2012. That was when Jason-1 was sent into a graveyard orbit about 13 km below its operational orbit. After inserting into that graveyard orbit insertion, Jason-1 was commanded to vent all of its remaining propellant. Note also that there are far fewer blips after March 2012 compared to before. This suggests some of the blips are issues with the algorithm used to create  TLEs while some are issues with short spans of data due to data rejected by the algorithm (presumably, before an orbit maintenance maneuver).

This is a good question!
I think if you look carefully, youll see:

spikes in some of the other parameters in those TLEs as well,
and if you propagate the TLE these will compensate each other such that the spacecraft's position won't be that far off from that predicted by the TLE before or after the "spikey" TLE.

TLEs are obtained by a fitting process, and a big challenge in fitting is correlations between fitting parameters.
For example if I only use data set from a fraction of an orbit, I can can vary semimajor axis and eccentricity in a way that maintains a similar altitude. That correlation would go away of course if the data set included points from both the perigee and apogee.
This is similar to what @RyanC suggests except it's not just the number of measurements but also how they are spaced out around the orbit and in time.
For more on this see:

my answer to Did Tiangong-1 turn the engines on?
Wikipedia's Correlation
Wikiepdia's Regression analysis search for "correlat"
Wikipedia's Pearson correlation coefficient


Sometimes NORAD struggles to get adequate sampling with available resources. At one point during the HETE-2 mission, they called the ops team to ask where HETE-2 was. They'd completely lost track.

@JohnDoty Yikes! :-) (related? Why did the frequency of TLEs for the Hubble Space Telescope drop by a factor of 3 in 2009?)

I looked at the other parameter, and what you are suggesting seems to be true, the changes are accompanied by corresponding, often smaller changes in other parameters.
If i understand your explanation correctly, basically when you are fitting the measurements, you can converge to a different set of elements that still reproduce the measured data. Do you think there is some way to distinguish between anomalies in TLE caused by algorithm failure and one cause by physical processes? Maybe looking at some combination of elements that would be more robust?

@klobaskasoslaninou That's almost the idea. If the measurements were perfect, and the model was perfect, you should always converge to the correct set of parameters. But when there is real-world error in the measurements and/or if the model is not exact, then of course you won't converge to the correct parameters. Often that results in a small random or systematic error. But if mathematically the parameters are correlated - if they "look like each other" then you can have much larger deviations. As to your "some way to distinguish between anomalies in TLE" question, hmm...

@klobaskasoslaninou Let's take a step back and remember what's happening. A series of angular and radial position and often radial velocity are made by (usually) radar, and a sophisticated orbit propagating calculation is made (based on a high-order model of the Earth's gravity field, the Sun's and Moon's gravity, and atmospheric drag effects) and varied, until the orbit trajectory has the best match to the measurements. THEN, a simple TLE is created from scratch, such that when you put it into an SGP4 propagator...

@klobaskasoslaninou ... it gives the best match to positions and velocities over a small period of time. Nobody cares what the values of the parameters are in the TLE, we only care if when you put it into SGP4 you get the best positions and maybe best velocities. Those parameters happen to have correlations, so you will see these blips and other artifacts, but it doesn't matter. That's why I wrote item #2 in the answer; I suspect that if you actually SGP4-propagate the "spikey" TLE and match it to propagations of the TLEs right before and right after it the positions are likely to match nicely

@uhoh thank you for clarifications. Just a small side note regarding the sgp4 propagations, I did use sgp4 propagator with given TLE data, but I wasn't looking at actual state vectors(position and velocity) but at "Mean Elements From Most Recent Propagation" which you can obtain from propagator. The errors persisted in those mean elements, but I believe that is expected.
